# Having an issue with One to Many Model Binder in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to make a create form for a One to Many (really many to many as two one to many relationships) entity. On form submission the model binder fails and I cannot figure out why its not binding. No fields from the submission are mapped to the model.

The create form works as expected. Then the submission appears as so:

```
facility.Name: TEST
facility.Code: TST
facility.RegionCode: AB
departmentFacility[0].DepartmentCode: ARR
departmentFacility[0].PrimaryRouterId: 4
departmentFacility[0].SecondaryRouterId: 1
departmentFacility[1].DepartmentCode: TFG
departmentFacility[1].PrimaryRouterId: 1
departmentFacility[1].SecondaryRouterId: 4
__RequestVerificationToken: *<removed>*
facility.Active: false
```

## Model

```
public class FacilityViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Boolean Active { get; set; }
        public string RegionCode { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DepartmentFacilityViewModel> DepartmentFacilities { get; set; }
    }

public class DepartmentFacilityViewModel 
    {
        public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
        public int PrimaryRouterId { get; set; }
        public int SecondaryRouterId { get; set; }
    }

public class FacilityDepartment
    {
        public IList<DepartmentFacilityViewModel> departmentFacility { get; set; }
        public FacilityViewModel facility { get; set; }
    }
```

## View

```
@using TEST.Models.FacilityViewModels
@model TEST.Models.FacilityViewModels.FacilityDepartment

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create Facility";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Facility</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.facility.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.facility.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.facility.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.facility.Code" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.facility.Code" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.facility.Code" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.facility.RegionCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.facility.RegionCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.facility.RegionCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="@Model.facility.Active" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.facility.Active)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <table>
                        <thead><th>Department</th><th>Primary Router</th><th>Secondary Router</th></thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @{
                            int cnt = 0;
                            List<FacilityDepartmentData> departments = ViewBag.Departments;

                            foreach (var department in departments)
                            {
                                @:<tr><td>
                                    <input type="checkbox"
                                            name="@($"departmentFacility[{cnt}].DepartmentCode")"
                                            value="@department.DepartmentCode"
                                            class="form-check-input" 
                                            @(Html.Raw(department.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                                            @department.DepartmentName
                                @:</td>
                                @:<td>
                                    <select asp-for="@department.PrimaryRouterId" name="@($"departmentFacility[{cnt}].PrimaryRouterId")" id="@($"departmentFacility{cnt}_PrimaryRouterId")" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RegionRouters"><option disabled selected>--- SELECT ---</option></select>
                                @:</td>
                                @:<td>
                                    <select asp-for="@department.SecondaryRouterId" name="@($"departmentFacility[{cnt}].SecondaryRouterId")" id="@($"departmentFacility{cnt}_SecondaryRouterId")" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RegionRouters"><option disabled selected>--- SELECT ---</option></select>
                                @:</td></tr>
                                cnt++;
                                }
                        }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Controller

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(FacilityDepartment facility)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(facility);
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View(facility);
                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync(User.Identity?.Name);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(facility);
        }
```

## Update

I was able to get this working by changing my controller code as such:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(FacilityDepartment facilityDepartment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Map the facilityDepartment to an entity class
                Facility fac = new Facility();
                fac.Name = facilityDepartment.facility.Name;
                fac.Code = facilityDepartment.facility.Code;
                fac.Active = facilityDepartment.facility.Active;
                fac.RegionCode = facilityDepartment.facility.RegionCode;
                fac.DepartmentFacilities = new List<DepartmentFacility>();

                foreach (var department in facilityDepartment.departmentFacility)
                {
                    if (department is not null)
                    {
                        var D = new DepartmentFacility()
                        {
                            PrimaryRouterId = department.PrimaryRouterId,
                            SecondaryRouterId = department.SecondaryRouterId,
                            DepartmentCode = department.DepartmentCode
                        };
                        fac.DepartmentFacilities.Add(D);
                    }
                }

                _context.Facilities.Add(fac);
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View(facilityDepartment);
                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync(User.Identity?.Name);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(facilityDepartment);
        }
```

Comment: @QingGuo Yes, I was able to resolve the issue. I updated the post with the new controller code that worked for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok a few red flags here. You appear to be mixing view models (FacilityViewModel) and entities. (FacilityDepartment) If you are using view models then stick to passing view models between views and controllers. The crux of the issue you describe usually comes down to the fact that the view is not storing enough information about the object model you expect to pass back. Since the view doesn't know about some of the related data in it's HTML, when the controller deserializes your object on a POST, things like relationships are left missing.

The main issue with passing entities between controllers and views and back is a misconception about what is coming back with a Form Post. You can write a View method that takes an entity as a model, load that entity from the DbContext and pass it to the view and everything seems fine provided that related entities are eager loaded, or you're Ok with the performance cost of lazy loading when the entity(ies) get serialized, provided the DbContext hasn't been disposed. However, the trip back to the controller in a Form POST is a completely different situation. It is ***not*** passing back the same entity that was sent to the view. When the controller sends a model to a view, that goes to the view engine on the web server to be mined and turned into HTML to send to the client. Your web browser doesn't have a copy of the .cshtml with Razor and a @Model, etc, that is the view engine that reads that. The web client gets the resulting HTML that the view engine produces. A Form POST or Ajax POST calls are coming from the client which is sending data the client extracts from this HTML. When you use a method signature that expects an Entity, all this means is that ASP.Net will attempt to populate an Entity class instance using the data the HTTP POST contains either in the arguments or body. It is not that original entity or even guaranteed to be a complete entity. This means that the view has to have all of the data needed in order to populate the models passed back, which is why you need things like hidden inputs etc. for values that aren't displayed in the view. Even then, an "entity" passed back to the controller is not really an entity, it is just acting as a detached view model. When it comes to object graphs (objects that contain references to other objects) this can cause even more problems if you treat those objects as entities. Say a Department has a reference to DepartmentHead being a User and I pass a facility with 3 Departments where 2 of those departments share the same reference to a DepartmentHead User. When we load the data from EF, those two departments would point to the same reference for that common user. However, even if we ensured that passing the facility with it's departments and department head data was passed back to the controller, when those objects are deserialized from the POST data, it will create 2 distinct instances of a User object for that same shared DepartmentHead User. This will cause exceptions and headaches when you try to attach the DepartmentHead to the DbContext to save the Facility as EF will attach the first instance from one Department, then complain that an entity with the same ID is already attached when you go to attach the second department's head.

In a nutshell, don't mix view models with entities, and essentially don't pass entities between controllers and views. Passing view models is accepting the fact that what comes into the controller is "just POCO data" that you will need to turn into entities. When you pass view models you need to ensure that all values are present and resolvable within the view, which often requires hidden inputs that will match a naming convention that ASP.Net's Javascript will search for to populate the form data. Personally if I need to pass object graphs I will generally use Ajax and build my view model structure explicitly rather than relying on ASP.Net's conventions with form data. Ideally I aim to avoid situations where I submit complex structures like one-to-many, and structure the application to submit changes more atomically using temporary session state to store changes until they are finalized at the top level when an overall "Save" or "Cancel" is selected. Once you're looking at POST data as just data you can send back from what is in the HTML then it should start shedding some light on how you can fix up ensuring that the needed information is available.